# Find the same sets of pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such scheme in *mysql*:

**TableA** (id integer PK, *pid* integer, *mid* integer)

Ex. data:

```
id  |  pid  |  mid  
1   |  2    |   2
2   |  2    |   4
3   |  3    |   4
4   |  4    |   2
5   |  4    |   4
6   |  3    |   2
7   |  3    |   5
```

I have *pid* with some *mid*'s and want to find all *pid*'s with the same set of *mid*'s. In example for `pid=2` answer is `2,4`

group_concat is not suitable for me

I think it should be simple, but the answer eludes me

**UPD**:
I have tried `group_concat`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.pid) FROM (SELECT pid, group_concat(mid) as concated FROM TableA where pid=100293) as a, (select pid, group_concat(mid) as concated, COUNT(1) as count FROM TableA group by pid) as b where a.concated=b.concated;
```

Comment: you question is not clear  .. you want  all the pid with  mid in (2,4) ?

Comment: show your query  ..  please or an equivalent based on the sample provided

Comment: FROM the sample data, expected result should be pids 2 & 4 because both pids have same set of mids (2,4). Is that correct or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with integers, instead of `group_concat` you could generate a bitmask on distinct `mid` values for each `pid` and join on that. Then it's just math all the way down:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pid 
FROM (SELECT pid, sum(pow(2,mid)) as midmask FROM (SELECT distinct pid, mid FROM tableA) as t1a GROUP BY pid) as t1
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT pid, sum(pow(2,mid)) as midmask FROM (SELECT distinct pid, mid FROM tableA) as t2a GROUP BY pid) as t2
        ON t1.midmask = t2.midmask
```

IF `mid` is already distinct for each `pid` then you can get rid of the inner-inner subqueries.

Using @GordonLinoff's excellent single-subquery approach where GROUP_CONCAT is only used on the main query (where it won't be so expensive). Instead of the group_concat on the inner query we use the bitmask approach that *may be* quicker.

```
SELECT midmask>>1, group_concat(pid) 
FROM (SELECT pid, sum(pow(2,mid)) as midmask FROM (SELECT distinct pid, mid FROM tableA) as t1a GROUP BY pid) as t1
GROUP BY midmask;
```

Results:

```
+---------+-------------------+
| midmask | group_concat(pid) |
+---------+-------------------+
|      10 |               2,4 |
|      26 |                 3 |
+---------+-------------------+
```

Obviously that midmask in the result set isn't super necessary, but you can pick out the values from the bitmask if you want to see the `mid` values that contributed to the match if you like.

I'm using the bit right-shift operator to insure that the proper bit is set in the midmask result otherwise you'll be off by one. If you don't care about the output of the midmask, then don't bother with the `>>1` portion of the query.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. It will give you comma separated pids.

```
select `mid`, group_concat(`pid`) from `tableA` group by `mid`;
```

Comment: Thanks. Group_concat is too slow. I have used it and time was about 1m. My query with `group_concat` will be in answer

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I would approach this using `group_concat()`:

```
select mids, group_concat(pid)
from (select pid, group_concat(mid order by mid) as mids
      from t
      group by pid
     ) t
group by mids;
```

This solves the general problem, for all pids.  Solving for 1 pid is a bit tricky in MySQL (no window functions), but you can try:

```
select t.pid, t2.pid, count(*)
from t join
     t t2
     on t.mid = t2.mid and t2.pid = 2
group by t.pid, t2.pid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.pid = t.pid) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.pid = t2.pid);
```

For this, you want indexes on `t(mid, pid)` and `t(pid)`.